# Change the page title to the last item in my breadcrumb with jquery

Tags: jquery, title, breadcrumbs

I am using a bread crumbing and need to change the page title to whatever the text is in the last breadcrumb. Is this possible?

```
<div class="span12">
<div class="breadcrumb clearfix">
<span itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" itemscope="">
 <a itemprop="url" title="domain" href="mydomain.com">
  <span itemprop="title">Home</span>
 </a>
</span>
  <span class="arrow-space">></span>
 <span itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" itemscope="">
    <a itemprop="url" title="tape" href="/collections/tape">
     <span itemprop="title">tape</span>
    </a>
 </span>
<span class="arrow-space">></span>
  <span itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" itemscope="">
    <a itemprop="url" title="black" href="/collections/tape/black">
      <span itemprop="title">black</span>
    </a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Not sure how to go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.title = $("span:last", ".breadcrumb").text() ​​
```

Comment: Actually, I'm getting an illegal character??

Comment: Did you add a ; at the end of the answer's line?

Comment: @user992731, could you clarify, which illegal characters you getting? I'm was sure that proposed solution and those that you posted below are identical.

Comment: looks like when I copy and pasted it grabbed an extra space at the end..my fault. Your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct!

```
 var newhefa= $(".breadcrumb").find("span:last").text()
 document.title = newhefa
```